# Reduce more than two new lines to one

Tags: php, regex

Whats the right way to reduce more than two new lines to one?

```
preg_replace('/[\n]{2,}/', "\n", "Hi,\nHow are you?\n\n\nI am just testing");
```

Returns:

```
Hi,
How are you?
I am just testing
```

Whilst, the expected result is:

```
Hi,
How are you?

I am just testing
```

The goal is to reformat the text of emails and change any spaces > 3 to 1

Thanks!

Comment: I think you have to clarify your question. The three line breaks are reduced to one, as you specified. Your "expected" output reduces the three line breaks to two. So what do you want?

Comment: And isn't that exactly what it does? In your expected results there is more than 1 new line. Seems the actual return is what you want?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your confusion is...  Replacing 2 or more `\n` with one `\n` will result in a single line break, which is what you get. From your example, you seem want a double line break. (A line break, then an empty line, then another line break.)

```
preg_replace('/\n{2,}/', "\n\n", "Hi,\nHow are you?\n\n\nI am just testing");
```

NB that I have also removed the unnecessary `[]` around the `\n` in the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps?

```
$string = str_replace("   ", "\n", $string);
```

or

```
$string = str_replace("   ", " ", $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just and improvement to an a previous answer.
From your example, you seem want a double line break. (A line break, then an empty line, then another line break)

```
preg_replace('/\n{3,}/', "\n\n", "Hi,\nHow are you?\n\n\nI am just testing");
```

{3,} because there is no need of matching/replacing two or less \n.
NB: i posted a new answer, because i don't have the reputation to add comment yet.